# How to optimize a sequential insert on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, typescript, knex.js

I'm trying to implement an HTTP event streaming server using MySQL where Users are able to append an event to a stream (a MySQL table) and also define the expected sequence number of the event.

The logic is somewhat simple:

1. Open transaction
2. get the next sequence number in the table to insert
3. verify if the next sequence number matches the expected(if supplied)
4. insert in database

Here's my code:

```
    public async append(
        data: any = {},
        expectedSeq?: number
    ): Promise<void> {
        let published_at = $date.create();

        try {
            await $mysql.transaction(async trx => {
                let max = await trx(this.table)
                    .max({
                        seq: "seq",
                    })
                    .first();

                if (!max) {
                    throw $error.InternalError(`unexpected mysql response`);
                }

                let next = (max.seq || 0) + 1;

                if (expectedSeq && expectedSeq !== next) {
                    throw $error.ExpectationFailed(
                        `expected seq does not match current seq`
                    );
                }

                await trx(this.table).insert({
                    published_at,
                    seq: next,
                    data: $json.stringify(data),
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.code === "ER_DUP_ENTRY") {
                return this.append(data, expectedSeq);
            }

            throw err;
        }
    }
```

My problem is this is extremely slow since there are race conditions between parallel requests to append to the same stream.. my laptop inserts/second on one stream went from ~1k to ~75.

Any pointers/suggestions on how to optimize this logic?

**CONCLUSION**

After consideration from comments, I decided to go with auto increment and reset the auto_increment only if there's an error. It yields around the same writes/sec with expectedSeq but much higher rate if ordering is not required.

Here's the solution:

```
    public async append(data: any = {}, expectedSeq?: number): Promise<Event> {
        if (!$validator.validate(data, this.schema)) {
            throw $error.ValidationFailed("validation failed for event data");
        }

        let published_at = $date.create();

        try {
            let seq = await $mysql.transaction(async _trx => {
                let result = (await _trx(this.table).insert({
                    published_at,
                    data: $json.stringify(data),
                })).shift();

                if (!result) {
                    throw $error.InternalError(`unexpected mysql response`);
                }

                if (expectedSeq && expectedSeq !== result) {
                    throw $error.ExpectationFailed(
                        `expected seq ${expectedSeq} but got ${result}`
                    );
                }

                return result;
            });

            return eventFactory(this.topic, seq, published_at, data);
        } catch (err) {
            await $mysql.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${this.table} auto_increment = ${this.seqStart}`);

            throw err;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you not using auto increment and let the server handle this?

Comment: autoincrement gets skewed with if there's any rollback on a transaction (expectedSeq does not match the inserted seq for example) and I might have issues with autoincrement once I implement snapshots

Comment: auto increment is the best solution here. explain "gets skewed".. if you mean it might skip one or not be in sequential order then yes that can happen, but they will still be unique. also not sure what problem there are with snapshots. If you need a clean sequence maybe try using an insert trigger to fill an additional column..

Comment: Can you identify which part is making it slow?

Comment: @tcadidot0 The slowest part of my initial snippet is the retry logic when there are race conditions in concurrent transactions. Also, there's a max query before every write, which already takes time. I tested max vs count and it seems count queries becomes slower the more records a table has where max doesn't.

In my latter snippet, the slow part is resetting the auto_increment pointer which makes on my laptop takes about 10 longer than a normal write query

Comment: All these operation are being executed in MySQL? If so, can you post the `EXPLAIN` on the count queries and resetting the auto_increment query? Thanks

Comment: @tcadidot0 I don't understand the question. these are simple one statement queries, there's nothing special about any of the queries

Comment: Here's the github page for the server: https://github.com/bahatron/mercurios

Comment: @Simon, you mention _"there's a max query before every write, which already takes time"_ so I assume this query is being executed in MySQL. Then _"max vs count and it seems count queries becomes slower the more records a table has where max doesn't"_  also I assume this one coming from MySQL. Even a simple query could be very slow if the table has no indexes. That is why I ask, if these queries are done in MySQL, can you provide an `EXPLAIN` on the queries and share with us the result? Thanks

Comment: 1. I meant that regardless of how well optimized the queries are, doing a SELECT and an INSERT will be inherently slower than doing only an INSERT statement 2. I loaded a table with 5million rows and noticed `SELECT count(id) from table` became quite slower than `SELECT max(id) from table`.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the web page need to provide the sequence number?  That is just a recipe for messy code, perhaps even messier than what you sketched out.  Simply let the `auto_increment` value be returned to the User.

1. `INSERT ...;`
2. `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`  -- session-specific, so no need for transaction.
3. Return that value to user.

Comment: is not a webpage, is not even a web service, there are many sessions of many HTTP servers (3 physical load-balanced servers, each running dockerized node.js clusters of 2-6 processes each) serving as interface for a kafka-like event streaming service

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro), It does all of this natively. With the easy answer out of the way, optimization is always tricky with partial information, however I think you've given us one hint that might enable a suggestion. You said without the order clause it performs much faster, which means that getting the max value is what is taking so long. That tells me a few things, first this value is not the clustered index (which is good news), second that you probably do not have sufficient index support (also good news since it's fixable by creating an index on this column, and sorting the index desc). This sounds like a table with millions or billions of rows in it, and this particular column has no guaranteed order, without the right indexing you could be doing a table scan between inserts to get the max value.

Comment: AFAIK, Kafka can only guarantee ordering of messages per Producer, which means if Producer 1 sends 1, 2, 3 and Producer 2 sends 4, 5, 6, you can still end up having `1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a GUID for your primary key instead of an auto-incremented integer? Then your client could generate the key and would also be able to insert it every time for sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch inserts versus singleton inserts

Your latency/performance problem is due to a batch size of 1 - as each send to the the database requires multiple round trips to the rdbms. Rather than inserting one row at a time, with a commit and verification after each row, you should rewrite your code to issue batch sizes of 100 or 1000 at a time, inserting n rows and verifying per batch rather than per row. If the batch insert fails, you can retry one row at a time.

Comment: That then pushes the responsibility of maintaining the order of sequence to the application, at that point SQL and transactions lose their appeal and I'd be better of using NoSQL / filestorage solutions for persistence